# Residue theorem with infinite series, sinh terms

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

I'm working through this paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep35222

In it, the authors have the following result from an integral obtained via the residue theorem (Eq. 24 in the attached paper: there is a missing factor of $\exp(i\lambda s)$ in their paper which I have restored here):

$$
\begin{align}
I &=-\frac{1}{16\pi^2 k^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{e^{i \lambda s}}{\sinh^2(s/2k-i\epsilon) - \frac{r^2}{k^2}\sin^2\Delta\theta/2}\mathrm{d}s \\
&=\frac{2\pi i }{16\pi^2 r\sqrt{1 + \frac{r^2\sin^2\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}}{k^2}} \sin \frac{\Delta\theta}{2}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2n\pi k \lambda} \bigg[ e^{-2ik\lambda\sinh^{-1}\frac{r\sin\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}}{k}} - \text{c.c} \bigg]
\end{align}
$$

I am unsure how they have proceeded from the first line to the second line. Particularly, I don't know how the infinite series arises  - there seem to be two poles at $s = \pm 2k \sinh^{-1} ( \frac{r}{k} \sin\frac{\Delta\theta}{2} )$, not an infinite number of them.

Any guidance on how this result is achieved would be very much appreciated!

Comment: $\sinh$ is periodic, the solution of $\sinh x = a$ is $x = (-1)^n \operatorname {arcsinh} a + \pi i n$.

Comment: @Maxim thank you for pointing that out! - I think that accounts for the terms in the infinite summation. I have been able to reproduce the result apart from the pre-factor in the denominator, namely $$ \sqrt{1+ \frac{r^2\sin^2\frac{\Delta\theta}{2}}{k^2}} $$ I understand this might come from a derivative from calculating the residue, however if I understand correctly, the singularities in the integrand are first order when you factorise it into $$(\sinh - a)(\sinh + a)$$ and then you can split this up into a sum of two terms (leaving the term in the bracket)? 

Am I missing anything obvious?